# Rails gem uses the development db instead of the testing one when executing "rake test"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, database-connection

I'm using a gem with my rails 3 project, "rails-settings-cached", and when I'm in development mode the gem can access the database without any problem.
However, when I run "rake test", a lot of tests fails because "rails-settings-cached" keeps using the development db instead of the testing one.

The other parts of my application works fine. What should I do to connect the gem to the right database?

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mmdb_development
  pool: 5
  username: ***
  password: ***
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mmdb_test
  pool: 5
  username: ***
  password: ***
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: can you group this gem (rails-settings-cached) under development only in the Gemfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that rails-settings-cached... well... caches the settings.
So, when you run your tests, it is actually using the old cached values from the "development" database.

A possible workaround can be running `rake tmp:cache:clear` before and after the tests.
It works, but to automate it you can put these methods inside **test_helper.rb**:

```
def setup
  Rails.cache.clear
end

def teardown
  Rails.cache.clear
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the caching in `rails-settings-cached` is that the default cache in Rails 3.2.8 (and probably in Rails 3 on) is `ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore`.  This caches to a file that is in a shared location and so is shared between development, test, and production.  This can cause all sorts of issues!

The [Caching with Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) claims that the default is `ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore`, but it appears that the documentation is incorrect.  I have submitted an issue against rails regarding the apparent documentation inaccuracy.

One solution is to switch test and development to using `ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore`.  If the default of 32 megabytes is enough, you can simply add the following line to both `development.rb` and `test.rb` in `config/environments` (inside the `.configure do` block, of course):

```
config.cache_store = :memory_store
```

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly set your rals env to test in test/test_helper.rb on the very top of the test_helper.rb file

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
```

Comment: Is your test helper actually being run?